# I am getting this error: "Flutter TabBarView Children Unable to Render Due to Unbounded Height"

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

I am getting this error:

> Flutter TabBarView Children Unable to Render Due to Unbounded Height

```dart
  Expanded(
    child: TabBarView(
      controller: tabController,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text("First view"),
        Text("Second view "),
      ],
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the TabBarView inside a container.Like this :

```
Container(  
  height: 200
  child: TabBarView(...)
)
```

Comment: i am expecting a list that's why i don't want to give a specific height to the container @Tasfiqul

Comment: Then you can give like this

Container(  
  height: [height of the list*number of list item]
  child: TabBarView(...)
)

Answer (score 0):

How many tabs you have declared in your TabBar?
anyway for unknown list of elements in tab view:
use SingleChildScrollView is amazing widget

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html

```
  Expanded(
    child: TabBarView(
      controller: tabController,
      children: <Widget>[
        SingleChildScrollView(
         child:Text("First view")
        ),
        SingleChildScrollView(
         child:Text("Second view")
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
```